# Fill missing values with closest row values in range of 5 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using this code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('wind.txt', header=0, delim_whitespace= True, index_col = True)
```

The Dataframe is something like this:

```
Date               Vel Dir
2016-07-12 16:15:00 2.8  1.8
2016-07-12 16:16:00 3.9  21.8
2016-07-12 16:17:00 9.8  4.8
2016-07-12 16:18:00 16.9 5.8
2016-07-12 16:19:00 17.0 7.1
2016-07-12 16:20:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 16:21:00 2.8  1.8
2016-07-12 16:22:00 3.9  21.8
...                 ...  ...
...                 ...  ...
2017-01-01 00:00:00 21.2  19.7
```

Sometimes the dataframe has a lot of missing data like here:

```
Date               Vel   Dir
2016-07-12 17:56:00 2.8  1.8
2016-07-12 17:57:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 17:58:00 9.8  4.8
2016-07-12 17:59:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:00:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:01:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:02:00 2.8  1.8
2016-07-12 18:03:00 NaN  NaN
...                 ...  ...
...                 ...  ...
2017-01-01 00:00:00 21.2  19.7
```

The first objective was to create a new dataframe, but instead time in 1 min use time in 3 hours. Using this code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start='2016-07-12 18:00:00',end='2017-01-01 00:00:00',freq='3H')})
```

Till here everything was ok, this generate a dataframe without Vel and Dir as spected and it's like that:

```
Date               
2016-07-12 18:00:00
2016-07-12 21:00:00
2016-07-13 00:00:00
2016-07-13 03:00:00
...        ...
...        ...
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

The objective now is to fill df2 with Vel and Dir values of df1 based on `Date`, but some data is missing. Knowing this I've tried merge_asof in this code:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2,df1, on='Date', tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5 minutes")).fillna('NaN')
```

It worked, but it only fills missing data with the first row before. The objective is to use values in rows after and before to fill missing data. Something like that:

```
Date               Vel   Dir
2016-07-12 17:56:00 2.8  1.8
2016-07-12 17:57:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 17:58:00 9.8  4.8
2016-07-12 17:59:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:00:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:01:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:02:00 2.8  1.8
2016-07-12 18:03:00 NaN  NaN
...                 ...  ...
...                 ...  ...
2017-01-01 00:00:00 21.2  19.7
```

Expected output:

```
2016-07-12 18:00:00 9.8  4.8
```

But if the dataframe is something like:

```
Date               Vel   Dir
2016-07-12 17:56:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 17:57:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 17:58:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 17:59:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:00:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:01:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 18:02:00 2.8  1.8
2016-07-12 18:03:00 NaN  NaN
...                 ...  ...
...                 ...  ...
2017-01-01 00:00:00 21.2  19.7
```

Expected output:

```
2016-07-12 18:00:00 2.8  1.8
```

The objective is do this to all dataframe, if does not exist any value in 5 min before or after Vel and Dir must be `NaN`. Would be helpful if someone could help.

Comment: In pandas version 20.1 there is a new option in [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=merge_asof#pandas.merge_asof) with parameter of `direction`, would 'nearest' help?

Comment: Actually it worked :-) thanks very much.

Comment: already upvoted =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use Pandas version 0.20.1 and `pd.merge_asof` with parameter `direction='nearest'`:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2,df1, on='Date', tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5 minutes"), direction='nearest').fillna('NaN')
```